# Thousands separator (comma) option for NumberString/StringCases?

Tags: string-manipulation

I've been looking for a way to read numbers that have thousands separators in them:

```
StringCases[" 1142.123 ",  Whitespace ~~ NumberString ~~ Whitespace, 1]
```

gives

```
{" 1142.123 "}
```

but

```
StringCases[" 1,142.123 ", Whitespace ~~ NumberString ~~ Whitespace, 1]
```

gives

```
{}
```

So ideally there's a Mathematica way of defining `NumberString` to recognize commas in numbers. Or should I be looking into regexen at this point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is admittedly a bit of a hack, but you could remove the commas first, using `StringReplace`:

```
StringCases[
 StringReplace[" 1,142.123 ", "," -> ""], 
 Whitespace ~~ NumberString ~~ Whitespace, 1]

(* ==> {" 1142.123 "} *)
```

Comment: This was the [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1801/52) I used for another [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1797/52), and as of yet, I don't see a way around it.

Answer (score 13):

I would just go to RegExp:

```
StringCases[" 1,142.123 ", RegularExpression["\\s[0-9,.]+\\s"], 1]

(* {" 1,142.123 "} *)
```

You could also go with:

```
ImportString[" 1,142.123 ","List"]
```

Though that will automatically change it to `Numeric`, which doesn't seem to be what you want...

Comment: +1 For anyone who understands regular expressions...

Comment: I think you meant `ImportString`, so I fixed it. I had forgotten about that function, +1.

Comment: `ImportString` does many tricks, but sometimes is too slow. Anyway it's a very good option if you don't want to build your own transformation.

Comment: @rcollyer oops, thanks. My MMA crashed for some reason, so I just typed from memory, but apparently had bad short-term memory

Comment: @EliLansey this made everything crystal clear: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ (sort-of) :)

Comment: @tkott Thanks. Looks like the obvious workaround! My favourite regular expression is http://internet.ls-la.net/folklore/url-regexpr.html ...

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are nice, but there is no *need* to use them here.

```
numString = (NumberString | ",") .. ;

StringCases[" 1,142.123 ", Whitespace ~~ numString ~~ Whitespace, 1]
```

> ```
> {" 1,142.123 "}
> ```

---

The form above is admittedly not robust as a valid number string should not start or end with a comma or have two decimal points, and I believe the comma should not immediately precede a decimal point or appear to its right side.  The easiest way I can think to preclude these is to check for them explicitly:

```
numString = x : (NumberString | ",") .. /;
   ! StringMatchQ[x, ",*" | "*," | "*.*,*" | "*,.*" | "*.*.*"];

StringCases[" 1,2. ,3 4, 5.6,7,.89 0.1.2sam, i am ", numString]
```

> ```
> {"1,2.", "3", "4", "5.6", "7", ".89", "0.1", ".2"}
> ```

Comment: @R.M maybe I need to *lern me my's RegEx*, but I believe tkott's pattern is equivalent (besides whitespace) to my *first* form: `(NumberString | ",") ..` in which case I would argue that, in the context of *Mathematica*, *his* is clunky. (Incidentally I already voted for his answer.)

Comment: I don't know regex well either :P I would've written something like this had I seen this question then too. I assumed his regex was equivalent to the second half of your answer, but on looking closer, I see that's not the case. Including all the exceptions would make his just as clunky, so comment revoked! :)

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward 7 years...

The reason your code didn't work as desired is because the stock string pattern, NumberString, was lamed. It could handle decimal points OK but not block separators such as commas and spaces (no matter how thin).

And now, 7 years later, with 12 it is *still* lame.

So one way to solve your problem is to build a less lame NumberString, one that can interpret block separators, even **very thick** spaces:

```
lessLameNumberString = n__ /; NumberQ[ SemanticInterpretation[n] ]
```

Now substituting back into your original code

```
StringCases[" 1,142.123 ", Whitespace ~~ lessLameNumberString ~~ Whitespace, 1]
```

gives

```
{" 1,142.123 "}
```