# Thousands separator for ToString

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, formatting

I am looking for the inverse of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5052/thousands-separator-comma-option-for-numberstring-stringcases), i.e., way to convert `100000` into a text `"100 000"` or `"100,000"`. I tried:

```
ToString[100000, TraditionalForm]
ToString[100000, OutputForm]
ToString[100000, Input]
ToString[DisplayForm[100000]]
```

but none of them yields the result that I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
ToString@NumberForm[100000, DigitBlock -> 3]
```

> "100,000"

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks!